# Relative error in Gaussian distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, floating-point

For discrete Gaussian distribution using cumulative distribution table how is the Relative error calculated?
Specifically, In this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/254 on page 7 section 3.4 It says that reversing the table will prevent blowing up of relative errors. I quite did not understand the reason very well.

Comment: So I'm not sure whether this is a one-tailed distribution or not, but I can definitely see the possible problem with a one-tailed distribution. Basically, if you sum a rapidly decreasing sequence of positive numbers in floating point arithmetic, soon enough you're going to start seeing something like $1+\epsilon_{mach}$, which will be just $1$.

Comment: So when you go to subtract the two neighboring terms, you will get just zero rather than a tiny positive number, which is a 100% relative error. Summing from the other way keeps the CDF small when the PMF is small, so that adding something to it makes a significant impact.

Comment: A concrete example albeit not in this context: $(1+2^{-100})-1$ will probably display $0$, whereas $(2^{-90}+2^{-100})-2^{-90}$ will not, even though both in theory should be $2^{-100}$.

Comment: What confuses me is that I usually think of a Gaussian as being two-tailed, and this problem cannot be eliminated in such a simple fashion in a two-tailed problem.

Comment: Since the gaussian is symmetric with 0, cant you just use the one-tailed and then have a 50/50 chance of being positive / negative ?

Comment: @MGirard I suppose that works (with appropriate modification if the mean is nonzero), it just didn't sound like that was what they were doing from what I got from the article. But maybe it was, I didn't read that carefully. It still doesn't work in a more general two-tailed situation with no symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not sure exactly what they're doing in this context, but I think I know essentially what is going on. The problem is essentially this: if you sum a rapidly decreasing sequence of positive numbers in floating point arithmetic, eventually the cumulative sum $S_n$ is way bigger than the next term $x_{n+1}$, which causes that term to be swamped, i.e. most or even all of its significant digits are destroyed. The remaining significant digits are all that you get when you attempt to reconstruct $x_{n+1}$ as $S_{n+1}-S_n$. But if instead you sum a rapidly *increasing* sequence of positive numbers, then the worst thing that could happen is that the cumulative sum itself gets swamped, which is not really a big deal in terms of computing $x_{n+1}$ as $S_{n+1}-S_n$.

One way to play with this (with less technical issues than in the article that you linked) would be to look at the distribution with $P(X=i)=\frac{2^{-i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{100} 2^{-j}}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,100$ and zero otherwise. Try computing the CDF by summing from left to right and then reconstructing the PMF, and then computing it again by summing from right to left and reconstructing the PMF. What you'll find is, if you're using IEEE double precision, the first method will actually just give $P(X=i)=0$ for $i$ larger than about $55$, while the second method will give reasonable results. This would be even worse if it were not for the fact that these numbers are all exactly floating point representable. You could try replacing $2$ with $3$ to see how much worse it can get.